# this is my code ; reading is over how to write the writing and updating in local xml file in android source code?

Tags: android, stream

```
public class LocalXMLActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // set the layout.. it refers main.xml
                                       // from the layout folder.
        InputStream is;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc;
        NodeList allTitles = null;
        String dataAll;
        try {

            // Input Stream is used to read the bytes. getResources refers to
            // the android resources(res)folder and open RawResource to the raw
            // folder under res. (res/raw)
            is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
            // Is to read the parser that prodcues from XML DOM.
            factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            // Once an instance of this class is obtained, XML can be parsed
            // from a variety of input sources. These input sources are
            // InputStreams, Files, URLs, and SAX InputSources. There are many
            // sources to take data from internet.
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            // the Document represents the entire HTML or XML document.
            // Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides
            // the primary access to the document's data.
            doc = builder.parse(is);
            // Retrieving the "company" node from xml
            allTitles = doc.getElementsByTagName("Company");

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataAll = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < allTitles.getLength(); i++) {
            dataAll += allTitles.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue() + "\n";
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView); // finds the
                                                               // widget"myTextView"
                                                               // from main.xml
        tv.setText(dataAll); // setting the dataAll value to myTextView.
    }
}
```

xml file:res/raw/data.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<content>
    <item>
        <Company>Google</Company>
        <Feature>Search Engine / Mail / Social Media</Feature>
        <url>www.google.com</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Company>Yahoo</Company>
        <Feature>Search Engine / Mail</Feature>
        <url>www.yahoo.com</url>
    </item>
</content>
```

the above code is only reading code,I have an XML file stored in the res/raw/data.xml that I am just reading, but how to write writing and updating in local xml file with inside reading source code write to writing and updating in local xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file on SD card like this:

```
File Directory=  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "working" +File.separator+"accounts");


File masterXMLfile = new File(Directory,"MasterCategories.xml");
                 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                  //Get the DocumentBuilder
                  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
                try {
                    docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  //Create blank DOM Document
                  Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();


                  //create the root element
                  Element root = doc.createElement("Categories");
                  //all it to the xml tree
                  doc.appendChild(root);
                  for(int i =0; i < nodeArray.length;i++)
                  {
                      System.out.println("entered into if loop");
                      Element subroot = doc.createElement("Category");
                      root.appendChild(subroot);
                      Element nameNode = doc.createElement("Name");
                      nameNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nodeArray[i]));
                      subroot.appendChild(nameNode);

                      Element thumbNailNode = doc.createElement("thumbnail");
                      thumbNailNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nodeArray[i]+".jpg"));
                      subroot.appendChild(thumbNailNode);
                      Element descriptionNode = doc.createElement("description");
                      descriptionNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nodeArray[i]+" data"));
                      subroot.appendChild(descriptionNode);
                  }
                  TransformerFactory transfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer= null;
                    try {
                        transformer = transfactory.newTransformer();
                    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

                    // create string from xml tree
                    // StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
                    FileWriter categoriesFW = null;
                    try {
                        categoriesFW = new FileWriter(masterXMLfile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(categoriesFW);
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    try {
                        transformer.transform(source, result);
                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                if(!masterXMLfile.exists())
                {
                    try {
                        masterXMLfile.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: thank you for u replay: this code is not using me.i want to local xml file and java file, in java file how to write the code to reading and writing  local xml file ,and automatically updating local xml file to write the code . plz give me a code

Comment: i have given the code for creating a local file in sd card if you want in other place change the path of the file other code will be the same

Comment: iam using the same code to create the xml file in a folder can i know where u got the error and what is the error

Comment: this code is some error is there,in this code main error nodeArray.length and nodeArray .this code how to create a local xml file in android

Comment: String []nodeArray = {"website","bank"}; this iam using in my code

Comment: how to create a local xml file in android

Comment: plz give me a local Xml file in android .Where i can store

Answer (score 0):

Well, honestly that is very confusingly written, but here is my thoughts:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/path/file.xml");
fos.write(byte_array_from_input);
fos.close();
```

That will write a file to your sdcard to /path/file.xml. You put in a byte array which you can either do in one go for small files, or in a loop if you have a large set of data.

Comment: thak you for u replay. bt my above code for reading is working, but how to write/update the things into my local xml file is not getting.

Comment: thank you for u replay: this code is not using me.i want to local xml file and java file, in java file how to write the code to reading and writing local xml file ,and automatically updating local xml file to write the code . plz give me a code

Comment: local xml file means where you want to store assets or else raw folder or else in data folder or else in sd card please mention